# How to get first column of all rows in a list in python

Tags: python, list, rows

could someone please help me with printing the first column of all rows in a csv file. I imported the csv file in python and when i make a list by using the code below, it prints all columns and all rows of the csv file. When printed in Python, the columns are seperated by a ';' instead of the usual ',' in a list. I would like to set all rows of the first column equal to a variable. I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

[click here to see the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpliE.png)

Comment: People can be more helpful if you share some code details. Like how do you imported the CSV, how do you hold it in the variable. Basically some code is needed for us to see where do you do wrong and propose a solution. Also, this will make the question more helpful for people struggling with same problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = pd.read_csv('your.csv') #reads csv file and stores in data variable
data.iloc[:,0] #prints first column
```